# 1 week from now at 8 o'clock

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'd like to get a DateTime that is 1 week from now at 8 in the morning.

Getting one week is easy:

```
DateTime.now + 1.week
```

How do I set the resulting date to a specific time?

Comment: Your question is not clear. What does "date at 8 in the morning" mean?

Comment: You wrote you want a date. Your code uses datetime. And then you want to convert a date to a time? Too confusing.

Comment: Recent versions of Rails use `ActiveSupport::TimeWithZone` instead of `DateTime`. You should do the same unless you have an old Rails version.

Comment: This! Better use ActiveSupport::TimeWithZone, `Time.current` instead of `DateTime.now`

Answer (score 24, accepted):

There are many ways to achieve this. Here's one:

```
Time.parse('8am') + 1.week
```

Here's another:

```
DateTime.now.beginning_of_day + 1.week + 8.hours
```

Or how about:

```
1.week.from_now.beginning_of_day + 8.hours
```

Or even:

```
DateTime.now.advance(days: 7).change(hour: 8)
```

Comment: you are awesome

Answer (score 7):

> [...] 1 week from now at 8 in the morning

I'd express that via:

```
1.week.from_now.change(hour: 8)
#=> Thu, 12 Oct 2017 08:00:00 CEST +02:00
```

[`change`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Time.html#method-i-change) automatically sets "smaller" time units (min, sec, etc.) to 0.

Answer (score 4):

Like this, for example:

```
(DateTime.now + 1.week).beginning_of_day + 8.hours
```